# missingness mechanism and missing rate

Tags: r, simulation, missing-data

I want to apply a missingness mechanism such as(MCAR,MAR,NMAR) to my data under missing rate (5%.15%) if I have tow variables and nine instances:

```
Aj <- c(48,75,83,58,83,32,45,50,86)
As <- c(24,30,31,35,60,76,81,82,88)
```

as follows:

for Simulating MAR, we first randomly separated the variables into pairs
(Aj, As), 1 ≤ j , s ≤ r, where Aj was the variable into
which missing values were introduced, and As was the variable
that affected the missingness of Aj . Given a pair of
variables (Aj, As) and missing rate α,we first split the instances
into two equal-sized subsets according to their values
at As . If the variable As is numerical, we would find the
median of As and then assigned all the instances into
two subsets according to weather the instances have bigger
values than median As. for  example we may let the instances
whose values at As are lower than the median 60 (instance
number 1–5) to be missing with the probability of 4α, that
is to say, Pr(Aj = missing|As ≤ 60) = 4α.

I wrote this code for missing mechanism  in R

```
ifelse(As<=median(As),Aj==NA,Aj)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA 32 45 50 86
```

My question is how to add missing rate for example 5% to this code in R  or another code for the above example and illustration.

Comment: `ifelse(As<=60,Aj==NA,Aj)` is the same as `ifelse(As<=60, NA, Aj)`

Comment: @jogo you are right but how to add 5% missing rate to it .

Comment: Can you rewrite this bit of your question "for Simulating MAR ,we first randomly separated the variables into pairs (Aj,As ), 1 ≤ j , s ≤ r, ", A_j and A_s are defined as arrays, now they are pairs of elements from the arrays? and where did r come from?

Comment: @Jonathan Lisic ,Let D denote an incomplete dataset with r variables
D = {A1,A2, . . . , Ar } and n instances. For each variable
Aj , j = 1, 2, . . . , r     or    As ,s = 1, . . . , r  ,   and about your answer I run your code but in the end b (# b is now Aj with missingness) dos not contain any miss value .

Comment: The one liner will produce zero to five missing values at a rate equal to 0.05.  The second tries to reproduce a set of observations with the given rate.  You should have at least one NA for the second bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner would give you missingness at rate alpha:

```
ifelse( (As <= median(As)) & (runif(length(As)) < alpha), NA, Aj)
```

If you want to have the observed rate close to alpha (you need to figure out how you want to handle rounding) you can do something like this:

```
 Aj <- c(48,75,83,58,83,32,45,50,86)
 As <- c(24,30,31,35,60,76,81,82,88)

 # missingness rate
 alpha <- 0.05

 # create subset less than the median
 b <- ifelse( As <= median(As) , NA, Aj) 

 # get the size of that subset (not known before hand due to tie handling)
 n.b <- sum(is.na(b))
 b.small <- Aj[is.na(b)]

 # sample from the small subset at a fixed rate, setting sampled to NA
 b.small[ sample(1:n.b, size=ceiling(n.b * alpha)) ] <- NA
 b[is.na(b)] <- b.small

 # b is now Aj with missingness
```

The output should be similar to

```
 [1] 48 NA 83 58 83 32 45 50 86
```

Comment: ,thanks alot for your help . Is b  MAC with % 5 missing rate exactly???. can I apply  this code for NMAR but change median(As) to median(Aj) ,and could you tell me how to check missing rate in my whole dataset manually and also in R language .